# Custom scheduler carousel in react js not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, carousel, react-ref

I am trying to achieve a custom scheduler carousel for daily view.
Here's my approach, but its not working currently.
code sandbox link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/wild-sky-7l319u
Refs are not working on clicking next or previous nothing is happening. I dont know maybe my previous and next logic is not working, but logging out the ref, showing it updates fine. What's wrong in this code and why is it not giving me the end result. what am I doing wrong here?

```
const DailyTable = () => {
  let time = [
    "12:00 AM",
    "01:00 AM",
    "02:00 AM",
    "03:00 AM",
    "04:00 AM",
    "05:00 AM",
    "06:00 AM",
    "07:00 AM",
    "08:00 AM",
    "09:00 AM",
    "10:00 AM",
    "11:00 AM",
    "12:00 PM",
    "01:00 PM",
    "02:00 PM",
    "03:00 PM",
    "04:00 PM",
    "05:00 PM",
    "06:00 PM",
    "07:00 PM",
    "08:00 PM",
    "09:00 PM",
    "10:00 PM",
    "11:00 PM",
  ];

  const boxRef = useRef(null);
  const boxRef2 = useRef([]);
  const addToRef = (el) => {
    boxRef2.current = [];
    if (boxRef2 && !boxRef2.current.includes(el)) {
      boxRef2.current.push(el);
    }
  };
  const previous = () => {
    boxRef.current.scrollLeft += -100;
    for (let index = 0; index < boxRef2.current.length; index++) {
     boxRef2.current[index].scrollLeft += -100;
    
    }
  };
  const next = () => {
    console.log(boxRef2.current.length);
    boxRef.current.scrollLeft += 100;
    for (let index = 0; index < boxRef2.current.length; index++) {
      console.log(boxRef2.current[index]);
      boxRef2.current[index].scrollLeft += 100;
    }
  };

 


  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Box sx={{ p: 3, borderRadius: "10px" }}>
        <TableContainer
          component={Paper}
          sx={{
            width: "calc(100% - 20px)",
            overflow: "hidden",
            borderBottomLeftRadius: 15,
            bottom: 0,
          }}
        >
            <Table>
              <TableHead>
                <TableRow>
                  <TableCell
                    align="center"
                    sx={{ width: "150px", fontWeight: 700 }}
                  >
                    Worker
                  </TableCell>
                  <Box
                    sx={{
                      position: "relative",
                      display: "flex",
                      alignItems: "center",
                      borderBottom: "1px solid rgba(224, 224, 224, 1)",
                    }}
                  >
                    <span
                      style={{ cursor: "pointer", marginTop: 7 }}
                      onClick={previous}
                    >
                      {" "}
                      <FaArrowLeft />
                    </span>
                    <Box
                      ref={boxRef}
                      sx={{ width: "calc(100% - 20px)", overflow: "hidden" }}
                    >
                      {time.map((item, index) => {
                        return (
                          <TableCell
                            key={index}
                            id={index}
                            sx={{ minWidth: 20, borderBottom: "none" }}
                          >
                            {item}
                          </TableCell>
                        );
                      })}
                    </Box>
                    <span
                      style={{
                        marginTop: 7,
                        cursor: "pointer",
                        position: "absolute",
                        right: 10,
                      }}
                      onClick={next}
                    >
                      {" "}
                      <FaArrowRight />
                    </span>
                  </Box>
                </TableRow>
              </TableHead>
              {workers.map((item, index) => {
                return (
                  <TableBody>
                    <Box
                      ref={addToRef}
                      sx={{
                        width: "calc(100% - 20px)",
                        overflow: "hidden",
                        position: "relative",
                        top: 1,
                      }}
                    >
                      {time.map((timeV, index) => {
                        return (
                          <TableCell
                            key={index}
                            id={index}
                            align="left"
                            sx={{
                              verticalAlign: "middle",
                              height: 77,
                              minWidth: 100,
                              p: 0.7,
                              borderRight: "1px solid rgba(224,224,224,1)",
                            }}
                          >
                            {item.assignWorks.map((work, index) => {
                              var mStart = moment(work.assignDetails.startTime);
                              var roundUpStartTime =
                                mStart.minute() ||
                                mStart.second() ||
                                mStart.millisecond()
                                  ? mStart.add(1, "hour").startOf("hour")
                                  : mStart.startOf("hour");
                              var width =
                                work.assignDetails.timeDiff == 0
                                  ? 106
                                  : work.assignDetails.timeDiff * 106;
                              let count = 0;
                              if (
                                roundUpStartTime.format("hh:mm A") === timeV
                              ) {
                                count += 1;
                                return (
                                  <Box key={index}>
                                    {(work.assignDetails.status === "pending" ||
                                      work.assignDetails.status ===
                                        "request") && (
                                      <Chip
                                      onClick={() => {
                                        setSelectedJob(work._id);
                                        setShowEditJob(true);
                                      }}
                                        label={work.name}
                                        sx={{
                                          mb: 2,
                                          borderRadius: "5px",
                                          fontWeight: 600,
                                          backgroundColor: `${colors.chip.lightBlue}`,
                                          color: `${colors.chip.Blue}`,
                                          width: width - 12,
                                        }}
                                      />

                            )}
                          </TableCell>
                        );
                      })}
                    </Box>
                  </TableBody>
                );
              })}
            </Table>
        </TableContainer>
      </Box>
    </Fragment>
  );
};
```

i tried to apply next and previous logic its not working. only thing i want if i click prev the refs should work accordingly.

Comment: Updating `ref` won't trigger a re-render, that's why you don't see the page update, use `useState` instead

Comment: @EnfieldLi how are states going to work here in this logic?

Comment: Looks like you need implement this with 2 states, one for the number `boxRef`, and another array `boxRef2`, see more on ["Updating Arrays in State"](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/updating-arrays-in-state) from the beta docs.

Answer (score 0):

One issue I can see in your code is that you are using `boxRef2.current = []` in your `addToRef` function. This will reset the `boxRef2.current` array every time the `addToRef` function is called. To fix this, you can use the `concat` method to add the new element to the existing `boxRef2.current` array.

Comment: @ign0rmaus is this your are saying ?
const addToRef = (el) => {
    if (boxRef2 && !boxRef2.current.includes(el)) {
      boxRef2.current = boxRef2.current.concat(el);
    }
};

Comment: @Jaydeee yeah, that’s right

Comment: Or you can just push to array, it doesn’t matter actually because it’s a ref

Comment: thing is its just working for the first time after adding scrollLeft to 100 it worked for the first time only

Comment: Did you fix addToRef function like I suggested you? And it worked for the first time after the fix?

Comment: yeah it just worked for the first time only